# Failed to load avro package in R

Tags: r, shared-libraries, avro, spark-avro

I have avro files in my local drive to read and i want these to be analysed through R. However this package is not getting installed. It is not available in cran so i had to download via GitHub. Here is the link:

https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/ravro/

I am getting the following error upon loading/installing in RStudio for this
ERROR: dependencies 'bit64', 'rjson' are not available for package 'ravro'

removing 'C:/Users/xyz/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ravro'
Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘C:/xyz/ravro/ravro-master/build/ravro_1.0.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Also when i run install_github("RevolutionAnalytics/ravro") it returns the error:

"Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:HTTP error 404.
Not Found Did you spell the repo owner (RevolutionAnalytics) and repo name (ravro) correctly? If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo."

Can anybody test and try to install this package and if its successful please let me know !

Comment: So you need to install the dependencies `bit64` and `rjson` first. Installation from github does not install dependencies automatically. Also note that repo not updated in 7 years, so there may be problems.

Comment: so it needed 4 dependencies Rpcc, rjson,bit64, bit and active java(1.6v at least) according to the git instructions . Still after installing these dependenices i am receiving error: * installing *source* package 'ravro' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ravro'
* removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ravro'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/User/ravro/ravro-master/build/ravro_1.0.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Sounds like you need to install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).

Comment: I already have Rtools installed

Comment: In that case "make not found" should not occur. Maybe try reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

downloading the file https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/ravro/blob/master/build/ravro_1.0.4.tar.gz
an than run

```
install.packages('path_to_tar.gz/ravro_1.0.4.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")
```

works on my machine